# Write for loop in batch file dynamically passed inputs from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I have a below requirment
A batch file that takes three parameters as input by prompting user to provide inputs from command line

1) Servername
2) Startdate
3) Enddate

Batch file should prompt in below manner.

```
Prompt Enter servername
Prompt Enter startdate
Prompt Enter enddate
Prompt user to ask if want to add one more set , IF enter Y , repeats the same 3 prompts, else, starts executing execute with single dataset 
Ex:-user enters server1 , 20130101 , 20130930 
asks to enter Y or N
If Y user enters server2 , 20130101 , 20130930 ,                                         asks to enter Y or N
If N, continues with 2 datasets
```

Now i need to write a for loop in batch file that repeats the same logic on 2 datasets
Can any one let me know how to accomplish this .
I am working on windows 7 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to get the data input:

The batch file tells you how to end data entry, and then it prompts for sets of data - I have shown two sets of data entered - and then it uses a loop to display the sets of data that were entered.

You can enter an unlimited number of data sets.

Here is the screen display:

```
Press enter when you have finished
Enter data in this format: servername,startdate,enddate \\server1,20010301,20010331
Enter data in this format: servername,startdate,enddate \\server2,20030102,20030103
Enter data in this format: servername,startdate,enddate

"servername=\\server1"
"startdate=20010301"
"enddate=20010331"

"servername=\\server2"
"startdate=20030102"
"enddate=20030103"

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the code: **edited with the extra functions from the comments**

```
@echo off
del data.csv 2>nul
set "MyLogFile=c:\temp3\copy.log"
set "targetdir=c:\temp3"
echo Press enter when you have finished
:loop
   set "data="
   set /p "data=Enter data in this format: servername,startdate,enddate "
      if defined data (
         >>data.csv echo %data%
         goto :loop
      )
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (data.csv) do (
   rem echo.
   rem echo "servername=%%a"
   rem echo "startdate=%%b"
   rem echo "enddate=%%c"
  pushd "%%a"
   for %%x in (*web_feed.out.gz) do (
      for /f "delims=." %%y in ("%%x") do (
         echo comparing server "%%a" : file "%%x"
         if %%y geq %%b if %%y leq %%c (
              echo      copying "%%x"
              echo              - date range %%b to %%c and %%y found
              copy "%%x" "%targetDir%\%%x" >> "%MyLogFile%"
         )
      )
   )
  popd
 )
pause
```

The file `data.csv` is used to store the sets of data entry, and is used in the for-in-do loop where it reads data.csv to echo the sets of data that were entered.

The second line deletes data.csv if it exists, so that a previous set of data will not be reused.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, just trying to understand before editing the script , what is data.csv in second statement , and what does that statement means ? and how it is useful in other parts of code ? please throw some light on it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, Actually i am using the below code  for each servername,startdate and enddate hardcoded
 SET server1=c:\temp1 
SET targetdir=c:\temp3 
pushd %server1% 
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "web_feed.out.gz"') do if "%%F" geq "20120101" if "%%F" lss "20120231" copy "%%F" "%targetDir%\%%F" >> %MyLogFile% 
popd
 pushd  %server2% 
Can you please let me know how above code can be put in your sugested  for loop ?

Comment: Fileformat Ex:- 20130512.001_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz       These are sample values i am sending from cmd prompt  \\server1,20130401,20130631 Similarly \\server2,20130501,20130730 ...etc

Comment: Entered first test data.c:\temp1,20130101,20130930
copied all files satisfying criteria as per logic.But for the below                                                  test data c:\temp1,20120101,20121231,its showing
comparing server logs "c:\temp1" : file "20121231.117_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz"
comparing server "c:\temp1" : file "20121231.118_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz"  and finally ended with out copying ,though the above files are satisfying condition, actually if %%y geq %%b if %%y lss %%c () condition is failing,due to which copy is not executed , Any guess why its happening?

Comment: Try entering the data again. Also make sure you have the latest revision of the code above - I edited it while posting it earlier.  You said that the `if` test is failing - what do you see on the screen?

Comment: its giving output in console, comparing server "c:\temp1" : file "20121231.117_visual_sciences_web_feed_out.gz", comparing server "c:\temp1" : file "20121231.117_visual_sciences_web_feed_out.gz" comparing server "c:\temp1" : file "20121231.117_visual_sciences_web_feed_out.gz"....................................... and finally press any key to continue. Actually after comparing , if condition should be satisfied as the filename matches the if date condition, and it should execute the loop (copying) , but faling the if condition

Comment: You have the same file and server listed three times above, but I think I see your issue.  I used your logic for comparing the dates but it has an error - the `lss` should be `leq` - try the edited code above.

Comment: yes, thanks for finding it, i just found it few mins back while retesting and was testing with diff scenarios, really excellent and thanks a lot for quick help, just need one more suggestion, Can we send the same arguments from another batch file , and call the second batch file from first batch file, can you let me please let me know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a do loop not a for loop. We don't have do loops in batch but can simulate one with the Goto command and Goto :Eof command.

So type

```
goto /?
set /?
choice /? (choice was removed from windows in XP or 2000, then upgraded, and put back in Vista)
if /?
call /?
```

so (note testing must be from high to low numbers). I also don't really know what you are asking so I can't work out what Y or N should actually do. So N executes another block of code and Y reasks the question.

```
:StartLoop
set /p sServerName=Enter Server Name
set /p sStartDate=Enter Start date
set /p sEndDate=Enter End date
choice /m "Enter Yes or No."
Rem Testing for N
if errorlevel 2 Goto AnotherBlockOfCode
if errorlevel 1 Goto StartLoop
goto :eof

:AnotherBlockOfCode
echo You chose No
goto :eof
```

If you need to Sub rather than jump use the call command.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for suggestion,For this batch file to execute I need 3 params,1)servername 2)startdate 3)end date,when batch is run,user is prompted to enter 3 params,then user should be prompted to enter Y/N,If Y, user will be prompted again to enter 3 params , after entering 3 parameters, again prompts to enter Y/N,if user enters N, now batch file should continue execution with only 2 sets of parameters,now do loop should run for 2 sets of parameters(as entered only 2 sets of parameters)that executes same logic,plz let me know with a simple example if possible

Comment: So basically ,once user enters Y, he will be prompted to enter 3 parameters again, entering N, will not prompt him further

Comment: No, even i am new to batch script .

Comment: though a bit complex as you told , but trying to accomplish it in batch script , please let me know if any suggestions in batch script itself

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set counter=0

:StartLoop
set /a counter=counter + 1

set /p sServerName%counter%=Enter Server Name
rem    set /p sStartDate%counter%=Enter Start date
rem    set /p sEndDate%counter%=Enter End date

set ss

If "%counter%"=="3" Goto AnotherBlockOfCode

choice /m "Enter Yes or No."
Rem Testing for N
if errorlevel 2 Goto AnotherBlockOfCode
Rem Testing for Y
if errorlevel 1 Goto StartLoop
goto :eof

:AnotherBlockOfCode
echo.
echo.
echo You chose No or already chosen 3 servers
echo.
goto :eof
```

Comment: Add I made the changes as mentioned above in my batch file and run it from command prompt cmd:>, it is not prompting me to enter the values, it is just printing the whole commands displayed cmd:> again

Comment: it displayed as below                
c:\Raja>demo.bat
offset counter=0:StartLoopset /a counter=counter + 1set /p sServerName=Enter Server Namerem    set /p sStartDate=Enter Start daterem    set /p sEndDate=Enter End dateset ssIf ""=="3" Goto AnotherBlock
OfCodechoice /m "Enter Yes or No."Rem Testing for Nif errorlevel 2 Goto AnotherBlockOfCodeRem Testing for Yif errorlevel 1 Goto StartLoopgoto :eof:AnotherBlockOfCodeecho.echo.echo You chose No or alre
ady chosen 3 serversecho.goto :eof

c:\Raja>

Comment: I observed that after echo statement it is combining off and set in second statement and printing whole code, I am unable to figure it out , I m using windows 7 , I m editing batch script in notepad++, do you have any idea why its combining off and set